# NPM erros when installing zombie 4.2.1 on Centos 6.7

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, zombie.js

I'm running a **vagrant** `bento/centos-6.7` box. My **node** version is `v6.9.1` and my **npm** version is `3.10.8`. When I run `npm install zombie@4.2` I get the following error:

```
node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/zombie-test/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../../nan/nan.h:43:3: error: #error This version of node/NAN/v8 requires a C++11 compiler
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:

/* stack trace */

make: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/zombie-test/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/vagrant/zombie-test/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

[Full stack trace here](http://pastebin.com/f8Y2XK8S)

Both node and npm were installed using [this instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/):

```
$ curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
$ yum -y install nodejs
```

Any known solutions for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a newer gcc/g++ version (the one that ships with CentOS6 is way too old). Take a look at this: http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/devtoolset/
- where you can update the building tools to decent/recent versions.